# Does this equation have any nonzero solutions

Tags: nt.number-theory

Does the equation

$$(a^{2}-b^{2})^{4}(a^{2} + b^{2}) = 4a^{2}b^{2} $$

Have any nonzero  solutions, where $a^2$ and $b^2$ are both rational ?

If yes, i suspect there should be infinitely many of them, can they be parametrized ?

Comment: Just to clarify: $a^2$ and $b^2$ need to be rational, but $a$ and $b$ need not be rational? In that case, why don't you write your equation as $(x-y)^4(x+y)=4xy$?

Comment: Why are you interested in this equation and its generalization?

Answer (score 10):

In any case there are only finitely many rational solutions. If I interpret your question correctly, you are looking for rational points on the curve $C$ given by
$$
(x-y)^4(x+y)=4xy
$$
where I have put $x=a^2$ and $y=b^2$. Taking $t = x/y$, we easily find that $y$ satisfies
$$
y^3 = \frac{4t}{(t-1)^4(t+1)},
$$
so that $C$ is birational to the superelliptic curve $C'$ given by
$$
\eta^3 = 4 \xi (\xi-1)^2 (\xi + 1)^2.
$$
We thus see that $C'$ is a triple cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$ which is totally ramified in $4$ points (including one above infinity), so by Riemann--Hurwitz $C'$ has genus $2$, so has finitely many rational points.

Comment: Just curious: how do you get the third display from the second? That is, what is the birational map $(x,t)\to(\eta,\xi)$?

Comment: I think it is simply $\eta = y(t-1)^2(t+1)$ and $\xi = t$.

Comment: Thanks. Also, in the second display, $x^3$ should really be $y^3$.

Comment: @Rene, thank you very much for your answer. Would you also please consider the more general equation: $$(x-y)^{4n}(x+y) = 4^{n}x^{2n}y^{2n} $$ where $x,y$ are rational and $n\geq 1$ is an integer ?

Comment: Do you mean $(x-y)^{4n}(x+y)=4^n x^n y^n$? Otherwise it does not have your original problem as a special case.

Comment: @Rene, exactly that's what i meant. Sorry for the typo.

Comment: In that case, the resulting superelliptic curve would be
$$
\eta^{2n+1} = 4^n \xi^n (\xi - 1)^2 (\xi + 1)^{2n},
$$
which is a $(2n+1)$-fold cover of $\mathbb{P}^1$, which again seems to be totally ramified in just $4$ points. Riemann--Hurwitz says the genus $g$ satisfies $2g-2 = -2 \cdot (2n+1) + 4 \cdot 2n = 4n - 2$, so $g=2n>1$. So by Faltings' theorem, there are only finitely many solutions.

Comment: Much thanks, but shouldn't one of the factors on the RHS of the superelliptic curve  be $(\xi -1)^{2n}$ instead of $(\xi -1)^2$ ?

Comment: No, I don't think so...

Answer (score 10):

Extending René's answer, the curve $C'$ is birational to
$$C'' \colon y^2 = x^6 + 4,$$
whose Jacobian variety has finite Mordell-Weil group isomorphic
to $({\mathbb Z}/3{\mathbb Z})^2$, from which it is easy to
show that the only rational points on $C''$ are thoses with $x = 0$
and the two points at infinity. From this, it is easy to get all
solutions to the original equation.

To get to this hyperelliptic equation, we rewrite René's equation as
$$(\xi^2 - 1) \left(\frac{\eta}{\xi^2-1}\right)^3 - 4 \xi = 0$$
and set $u = \eta/(\xi^2-1)$. Taking the discriminant of
$u^3\xi^2 - 4\xi - u^3$ as a polynomial in $\xi$ gives
$$4 + u^6 = v^2$$
as claimed. The points with $u = 0$ give $\eta = 0$, so $y = 0, x, -x$,
which leads to $x = y = 0$. The points at infinity have $\xi = \pm 1$,
which gives the same result.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. Would you also please consider the more general equation: $$(x-y)^{4n}(x+y) = 4^{n}x^{2n}y^{2n} $$ where $x,y$ are rational and $n\geq 1$ is an integer ?

Comment: Typo in my above comment: the factor on the RHS should be $x^{n}y^{n}$, not $x^{2n}y^{2n}$.

Comment: For larger $n$, the curves will no longer be hyperelliptic, so the machinery that I used to deal with $n = 1$ is no longer applicable.